# SaaS - Single application but separate db approach - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, saas

I was about to create my first SaaS application. Thought about creating a single front end application, but separate db for each client.

But before starting, did some research and found this whitepaper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Note sure whether I completely understood the things mentioned in there. But I felt like an isolated, ie. separate database per client is better. Because it allows us to easily backup or restore the db for each client, separately.

Here also, the user is suggesting to use separate db: [Multi Organization SaaS mySQL Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148158/multi-organization-saas-mysql-setup)

So, I would be keeping a main database to hold the client info which includes the database name created for that client. The thing that I am having trouble with is, shall I create a single db_user and associate this db_user for all databases ?

Or do I have to create separate db user and attach it to each db ? That is, each db has a different db user.

For example:

```
DB Name     | DB User
------------------------
abc_db1 ----|     
abc_db2 ----|     
abc_db3 ----|---> dbuser   
abc_db4 ----|     
abc_db5 ----|     


DB Name     | DB User
---------------------
abc_db1 ----> dbuser_1
abc_db2 ----> dbuser_2
abc_db3 ----> dbuser_3
abc_db4 ----> dbuser_4
```

Among the two, which one would be the better option to use ? A single db user for all DBs or separate ones for each ?

Thank you

Comment: i have a SAAS project like this, we use one db user.

Comment: What I would recommend is doing both. Have your SaaS administration use its own user that is permitted to access all of the databases in question, and create a unique user for each DB that each client will use. That way you can limit access by client to a specific user, but still manage everything with a single user for yourself. Just be certain to make the universal user have restricted access (such as only localhost or whatever your web server's IP(s) are).

Comment: Thank you Dagon and Mark Ormston.